# How do I easily dispatch a ghast in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I went through a portal and I had three ghasts right above the portal. I ran to hide, and I had to wait for my brother to come and save me. Could I have fought the ghasts and won easily with a wooden sword?

Comment: Nothing is easy to dispatch in this game with wooden swords, unless you have mad juke skills. Youre better off saving the wood to make a pickaxe, mine some stone, and make a stone sword. Even then, things wont be outright easy to kill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ghasts can be tricky, but manageable if you know what you're doing. Personally, I prefer to use a bow to kill ghasts. They don't have a lot of hitpoints, and an unenchanted bow can kill a ghast in 2 shots according to the wiki. Another option is to reflect their fireball, which is an instant kill and an achievement, but this is riskier, and more difficult.

Another thing to keep in mind is that ghast fireballs cause a small explosion, which is enough to destroy some blocks like netherrack, sandstone, dirt, and can even put out your nether portal. But, it is not strong enough to destroy cobblestone. The first thing I do when entering the nether is construct a stone shelter around my portal to at least keep me from getting trapped in the nether.

Comment: +1 for the cobblestone advice. I agree, bows are the way to go.

Comment: The bow charge time is almost identical to the ghast firing interval, so it's better to dodge one fireball and shoot an arrow afterwards, otherwise you just hit the fireball with your arrow. And if you have iron, a crossbow might actually be a very good option.

Comment: Also, cobbled deepslay

Comment: deepslaye has the same blast resistance as end stone if you’re using 1.18 :)